# Exporting one to many relation in QGIS to new shapefile?

Tags: qgis, relates, one-to-many

I am using QGIS 3.4.1-Madeira.

I have a base layer map that represents areas as polygons. I have created a CSV file with many entries of different NGO projects, and each one is coded with the ID of the spatial area it takes place. I understand I can't do a simple Join because it only joins one row of the CSV to each area polygon. I have set up a Relation in the Project Properties, which reflects the data structure I want, but I can't figure out how to make it just display in the map as a new layer.

Comment: As far as I can see, shapefiles can store only 1:1 relations and a clean way to realize a one to many relation is using some database format, e.g. spatialite and store both tables. Unfortunately a related table, like in the ESRI-world, has no equivalent in a database.

Comment: you should read about virtual layers concept of QGIS, it offers a lot of possibilities known from databases like joining data and building new layers based on that join. Just as a starting point (the concept is the same in QGIS 2.18 and 3.4): https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest `Join attributes by field value` tool (though I am conscious this is not a direct answer to your question: how to utilize your established Relation).

This tool joins two tables using `key` field from each table. Its `Create separate feature for each matching feature (one-to-many)` option allows us to create `one-to-many` relational table, extending (duplicating) one record to match with many other records in the other table.

[image]